# Derivative of integral whose boundaries are both variables

Tags: calculus

> Given $F(x)=\int_{x^5}^{x^3}(2t-1)^3dt$, find $F'(x)$

---

How do I use the fundamental theorem of calculus when both lower and upper boundaries are variables?

What I tried doing was splitting the integral into 3 intervals, interval 1 at $[1, x^3]$, interval 2 at $[x^3, 4]$, and interval 3 at $[4, x^5]$. For the second interval, I switched boundaries to make the variable the upper boundary, then multiplied my integral by $-1$. Doing all of this got me
\begin{align*}F'(x)&=(2x^3-1)^3-(2x^3-1)^3+(2x^5-1)^3 \\ F'(x)&=(2x^5-1)^3\end{align*}

Can somebody please verify if I am correct?

Comment: This should help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're asking this question, I am assuming you did not do the Leibniz integral rule, so if you're trying to avoid using any theorems you didn't do, you could just write $$F(x) = -\underbrace{\int_{0}^{x^5} (2t-1)^3\text{d}t}_{:= G(x)} + \underbrace{\int_{0}^{x^3} (2t-1)^3\text{d}t}_{:=H(x)}$$ and then use substitutions $u = x^5, v = x^3$ respectively to obtain $$G(x) = G(\sqrt[5]{u})=\int_0^u (2t-1)^3\text{d}t\implies G'(\sqrt[5]u)\cdot(\sqrt[5]u)' = (2u-1)^3\implies G'(x) = 5x^4(2x^5-1)^3,$$ $$H(x) = H(\sqrt[3] v) = \int_0^v (2t-1)^3\text{d}t\implies H'(\sqrt[3] v)\cdot(\sqrt[3] v)'=(2v-1)^3\implies H'(x) = 3x^2(2x^3-1)^3.$$ Altogether, this gives $$F'(x) = 3x^2(2x^3-1)^3 - 5x^4(2x^5-1)^3.$$

Using very similar arguments, you should be able to prove the more general Leibniz integral rule.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental theorem of calculus applied to$$F(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) \, dt$$ gives
$$F'(x)=f(b(x))\, b'(x)-f(a(x))\, a'(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varphi$ a primitive of $t\mapsto (2t-1)^3$, then
$$ F(x)=\varphi(x^3)-\varphi(x^5) $$
so that
$$ F'(x)=3x^2\varphi'(x^3)-5x^4\varphi'(x^5)=3x^2(2x^3-1)^3-5x^4(2x^5-1)^3 $$

Comment: Can you provide a solution purely in terms of x? My homework will not allow $\varphi$